# Backbone Collection length vs size()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, underscore.js

It seems redundant to me that [Backbone Collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) have both a [length](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-length) property and [size](http://underscorejs.org/#size) function that return the same result. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is the size of a particular backbone collection (the length property) the other is a method of the underscore library which can return the size of ANY collection = specifically useful for arrays, lists and anything else it might support.

It's here because all the methods are mixed into a Backbone collection as a convenience thing by the library. It should be noted that this is also a method call -- and not a computed property as well, so it would technically be slower as well to call `size` instead of just checking the maintained length.

In the interest of sticking with documented API(s) via Backbone itself, you are better off just using `length`

Answer (score 0):

length is a property and will be available only on arrays type, where as size is a method and will be available in most data structure objects like Set, List, etcc..